# Blocking producers in active mq

Tags: timeout, activemq-classic

Lately we have been facing some issues with activemq. Producers are able to connect to the broker but when we send a message, the producer thread is blocked. The client/producer neither times out nor throws an exception. I would like to know if there we can add any parameter to the failover config **failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://srv01.abc.com:61616)**, so that if the client timesout on primary, the message can be redirected to the failover mq broker. Would be great if anyone can help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

So for failover transport :

> `maxReconnectAttempts`: Default Value = -1 | 0
>
> **From ActiveMQ 5.6**: default is
>   -1, retry forever. 0 means disables re-connection, e.g: just try to connect once. **Before ActiveMQ 5.6**: default is 0, retry forever.  All
>   ActiveMQ versions: a value >0 denotes the maximum number of reconnect
>   attempts before an error is sent back to the client.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://srv01.abc.com:61616)?randomize=false&maxReconnectAttempts=Value&trackMessages=true")
```

All failover Transport Options can be set in the url

http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Hassen. Would like to know if we need to set the maxReconnectDelay also and does the attribute maxReconnectAttempts take care of redirecting the request to failover nodes if the the reconnect attempts are exhausted on primary?

Comment: the maxReconnectAttempts is the max for all failover url's, FailoverTransport automatically tries to connect to url's one by one and if it cannot connect successfully to one url he tries the next one, this whole process is equal to an "attempt" 1 of maxReconnectAttempts

Comment: FailoverTransport always take care of redirecting the request to failover nodes if the the attempt on a node fails

Comment: Sure. Will check and let u know.

Comment: You may also need to define `connection.sendTimeout` so that after those many seconds connection would timeout otherwise it would not because default of 0 which means never timeout, if you do not timeout then `maxReconnectAttempts` wouldn't be useful.

Comment: I tried with only maxReconnectAttempts..looks like if the primary is down the client connects to failover to send the message but the wouldn't try sending the subsequent messages even if the primary is back up.

Comment: @hagrawal...can I use connection.sendTimeout in java?from http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html looks like it can be used only with activemq-cpp library..